# Does the Healing Domain (or similar metamagic-like effects) affect scroll/wand/staff use?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, metamagic, spellcasting, domains

Many abilities, notably the [Healing Domain](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains/paizo-domains/healing-domain/) 6th level feature, allow you to alter "your spells" with metamagic-like effects.

> At 6th level, all of your cure spells are treated as if they were empowered, increasing the amount of damage healed by half (+50%). This does not apply to damage dealt to undead with a cure spell. This does not stack with the Empower Spell metamagic feat.

Does this feature (and/or others like it) apply when casting a spell through a scroll, wand, or staff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## No.

<sub>*Shamelessly stolen from [Hey I Can Chan](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/8610)'s [Comment](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/152941/#comment396639_152949).*</sub>

There exists this [FAQ](https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9n9y), which states:

> **Items as Spells: Does using a potion, scroll, staff, or wand count as "casting a spell" for purposes of feats and special abilities like Augment Summoning, Spell Focus, an evoker's ability to do extra damage with evocation spells, bloodline abilities, and so on?**
>
> No. Unless they specifically state otherwise, feats and abilities that modify spells you cast only affect actual spellcasting, not using magic items that emulate spellcasting or work like spellcasting.

Therefore, abilities or feats of a character never affect a spell cast by a magic item (unless they specify otherwise).

Comment: (Credit appreciated but unnecessary. The reason I didn't put this as an answer—although I think Paizo's staff would consider it accurate—is that it applies only to "spells you cast" and, strictly speaking, you may not be casting "all of your *cure* spells," and, may, instead, be causing *cure* spells to come into effect by a means other than you casting them—like by activating a wand. I know, right?)

Comment: I'm going to give the answer to this one because of how concise it is; I did upvoted KRyan's answer for providing context

Answer (score 3):

> all of your cure spells

When you activate a spell-completion or spell-trigger item (e.g. a scroll or a wand), you are casting a spell—but I think it’s quite a stretch to say it is *your* spell. This is backed up by my general experience where item-derived spells did not benefit from this kind of thing; it seems at least to me that a general consensus exists on this.

Paizo does have an [FAQ entry blocking class features on item-granted spells](https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9n9y), confirming that. Note that this **is** inconsistent with how class features behave—see [this FAQ entry on those working for all classes’ spells](https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9ne8)—but it matches my general experience of how most people play. In any event, these are only really relevant for things that are similar to the healing domain, but don’t include that crucial “your” in the description. For the healing domain, the “your” means that there really is no way to argue that item-granted spells should benefit.

Finally, let me just say that, the healing domain is pretty awful. Markedly improved over the 3.5e version, no doubt, but still quite poor. All of the spells are already cleric spells, so you don’t get one of the best potential benefits of a cleric domain, and healing in general is pretty underpowered so focusing on it like this is a bad idea. I wouldn’t want to say domains apply to item-derived spells in general, since I suspect there are domains where I’d end up regretting that, but for the healing domain specifically, allowing it to apply to items would suddenly make it worth possibly considering. That’s a lot better than considering the domain to basically be a pure trap option, which is about how I’d judge it as is.

Comment: Well currently I'm loving my Restoration subdomain Cleric who keeps everyone alive,all the time, so they can do damage or cc for me. It's like being 1-4 characters per encounter, depending on how deadly it could have been. Approval of the domain aside, is it fair to say you think it doesn't work RAW but would be a viable home-rule?

Comment: +1. Parties I DMed were using wands and services for healing most of the time, and that domain was never selected. Allowing domain to apply to wands sounds like a great idea to make it more attractive.

Comment: @Ifusaso My discussion of the healing domain refers only to the domain itself, not to any subdomain—I haven’t even read any of the subdomains. Anyway, yes, that is a fair conclusion.

Comment: You might be thinking of [this exchange](https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9n9y), but I agree that "all of your *cure* spells" is the kind vague statement that I increasingly suspect Paizo deliberately includes in their products to drive traffic to their messageboards.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Yeah probably that’s the one.

Comment: @williamporter Fair enough: my recollection of the entry that HeyICanChan linked to was that it superseded that, which is why I thought it was so dumb, but it was narrower, just focusing on items, while the previous only focused on classes. There’s still an inconsistency there, but a less problematic one.

Comment: @williamporter Corrected.